# Create JSONArray of JSONObjects using AFNetworking 2.0 in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

**-** The structure that I am trying to create is

```
[{'category_id': '3'}, {'category_id': '2'}, {'category_id': '1'}]
```

**-** I tried creating the same using `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` & the structure that i got back was:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7c186080>(
{
"category_id" = 1;
},
{
"category_id" = 2;
},
{
"category_id" = 3;
}
)
```

**-** I am sending this to server over `HTTPPost`.

**-** But on the server the request is reaching as:

```
{(null)[][category_id]': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Which is not in the desired format as i showed above in point 1.

**-** Can anyone please help me out create an `JSONArray` of `JSONObjects`, I would be really obliged.

**The code that i used to create and send the request to server is:**

```
-(void) getProductList:(NSString *)strToken andCatId:(NSArray *)arrCategory{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:strToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


NSString *strSuffix = @"unfollow/productList/";
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,strSuffix];

api_categoryProductList *currentObj = self;


[manager POST:strUrl parameters:arrCategory success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
[currentObj httpOperationDidSuccess:oper
ation responseObject:responseObject];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [currentObj httpOperationDidFail:operation error:error];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:id forKey:@"category_id"];
    [array addObject:dict];
}
```

Right now it has static id as 1. You can change it to whatever value you like.